# Mocking property of type DateTimeOffset results in InvalidProgramException in a Windows Store Test library

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, windows-store, moq-rt

I just started out with a Windows Store application and deciced to use test-driven development in my project. Since I've had some experience with NUnit previously that was my library of choice, and then I started using MoqRT which was the mocking library recommended by a website as the mocking library to use for Windows Store applications.

The problem I am facing is when I'm mocking an object that has a `DateTimeOffset` as the type of the property. I receive the following exception:

> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program
> at Castle.Proxies.ITimeProxy_1.get_Expires()
>
> ...*the rest of stacktrace removed due to clarity*

Now, this *only* occurs when I use the `DateTimeOffset` type on the property, and mocking for instance a string property works perfectly fine.

```
using System;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace StoreTesting
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            // Mock
            DateTimeOffset expirydate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(2000);

            var time = new Mock<ITime>();
            time.Setup(m => m.Expires).Returns(expirydate);

            // Act
            TimeDependant obj = new TimeDependant(time.Object);
            var result = obj.Act();

            // Assert
            Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(expirydate));
        }
    }

    public class TimeDependant
    {
        private readonly ITime time;

        public TimeDependant(ITime time)
        {
            this.time = time;
        }

        public DateTimeOffset Act()
        {
            return time.Expires;
        }
    }

    public interface ITime
    {
        DateTimeOffset Expires { get; }
    }
}
```

If I subclass `ITime` and use that instead of the Mock, everything is just fine as well.

When searching for this it seems as though the main problem of the exception is related to "too large methods", but seeing as this only occurs for properties of type `DateTimeOffset` I don't see how that can affect my test, since other properties should fail as well if it was something in regards to that.

Another thing is that I'm running the tests using the NUnit application, as the tests won't run in Visual Studio 2012 due to it being a Windows Store application (which is a whole other question). I don't know if this can affect the behaviour as well.

The question I'm asking is; Is there a way to mock interfaces with properties of type `DateTimeOffset` without having it throwing an exception?

Comment: This occurs because value types doesn't return the mocked value. This is described at the project site, *"MORE CAUTION: There is a bug in this current version that stops integer return values from being processed property. (e.g. Setup(...)...Returns(...) where Returns is an integer type.) Use strings at this point. This will obviously be fixed as a matter of urgency."* - https://github.com/mbrit/MoqRT

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Moq with Windows Store Runtime as I know, because [winrt doesn't allow dynamic codegen](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/moqdisc/nP5kS_ZNZP0).

I do it just thought creating simple .NET Framework library, which reference all my code, which I want to test, from Win Store Project

[How to use Moq and nUnit to write Unit Tests for Windows Runtime libraries](http://outcoldman.com/en/blog/show/332)

Comment: No, you can use Moq for Windows Store applications, it's available at https://github.com/mbrit/MoqRT. It works for nearly everything, apart from my question above. :-)

Comment: Also, even if I use a "regular class library", I still get the same exception. So this doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Got it. Please update your question then with information that you are not using the Moq library, that you are using MoqRT library.

Comment: @Patrick btw, when you are using "regular class library" - you need to use Moq library, not the MoqRT - and everything should be fine.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course! You're right. When using Moq with a Unit test library, the test passes, and there's no exception. I would still like to know why this won't work with the MoqRT library though. If I won't get an answer I will probably have to resort to the solution you provided.

Comment: When you showed me a link with MoqRT - first thought was `Oh! great! I need to try it!`, when I've read requirements and steps to set it up... `I will keep my approach for a while`. :)